# Wrong order of task execution in gradle 3.3

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

I want to define methods inside my script file, and use them to define build tasks for each project individual (custom library).

```
ext.buildDockerImage = { imageName ->

    def distDir = "${getProject().getBuildDir()}/docker"
    copy {
        from "${project.getProjectDir()}/src/docker/"
        into distDir
    }
    println 'Build docker image'
}
```

In my project `build.gradle` I have created a task:

```
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

dependency {
  // all dependencies
}

task buildDocker() {
    apply from: "${project.getRootDir()}/docker/scripts.gradle"
    buildDockerImage("admin")
}
```

The problem is that whenever I am running `gradle build`, this tasks executes also:

```
 $ gradle build -xtest
Build docker image
# rest of build
```

As you can see , all I want is to create a custom library that will hold methods, used to create tasks for each project. But currently I cannot import those methods without breaking the build. Method `buildDockerImage` will work only after war file is added to build directory, so this task must be executed on demand only, I don't want to be included in the process all the time.

My questions:

- how make my task to only run when I execute task manually
- why, when I execute my build, script executes as first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task `buildDocker()` defines everything in configuration phase. So when you run your gradle build this will always run.

```
task buildDocker() {
    apply from: "${project.getRootDir()}/docker/scripts.gradle"
    buildDockerImage("admin")
}
```

If you want to run this task as a standalone task, define your stuff in execution phase of the task. something like below

```
task buildDocker() {
  apply from: "${project.getRootDir()}/docker/scripts.gradle"
  doLast{
    buildDockerImage("admin")
  }
}
```

[Read This article](http://www.ekiras.com/2016/12/gradle-build-life-cycle-phases-gradle.html)

This might help

Comment: It worked:) I was so close to solution, thank you for your help:)